# How to output a multi dimensional array in Keras?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I have this CNN in Keras where output is a 2d array of bounding boxes,
The shape of output is

```
(18, 4)

x_train shape = (None, 600, 750, 1) # grayscale
y_train shape = (None, 18, 4)
```

I am getting the following error:

> ValueError: Error when checking target: expected dense_2 to have 2
>   dimensions, but got array with shape (1, 18, 4)

```
model = tf.keras.models.Sequential([
    tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(32, kernel_size=(3, 3), input_shape=(h, w, 1),
                           strides=(2, 2), padding="same", activation="relu"),
    tf.keras.layers.MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2), strides=(2, 2), padding="same"),
    tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.25),

    tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(64, (3, 3), strides=(2, 2), padding="same", activation="relu"),
    tf.keras.layers.MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2), strides=(2, 2), padding="same"),
    tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.25),

    tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(128, (3, 3), strides=(2, 2), padding="same", activation="relu"),
    tf.keras.layers.MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2), strides=(2, 2), padding="same"),
    tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.25),

    tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(512, (3, 3), strides=(2, 2), padding="same", activation="relu"),
    tf.keras.layers.MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2), strides=(2, 2), padding="same"),
    tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.25),

    tf.keras.layers.Flatten(),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(1024, activation="relu"),
    tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.5),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(18)
])

model.compile(loss="mse", optimizer=tf.keras.optimizers.RMSprop(), metrics=["accuracy"])
model.fit(x_train, y_train, epochs=1)
model.save("trained_model.h5")
```

Comment: What are the shape of your x_train and y_train ?

Comment: Reshape the target labels to `(18, 4 )`, since the output dimension for the last Dense layer is 18. Use `numpy.reshape()`.

Comment: shape of x_train is (5000, 600, 750, 1)
shape of y_train is (5000, 18, 4)